# Existence and unicity of a probability : $\sum_{\omega\in \Omega}\Bbb{P}(\{\omega\})=1$

Tags: probability

I am working on probability course, and given a coin thrown $n$ times, and let $\Omega:=\{P,F\}^n$ (heads or tails : Pile ou face).

> Let $P_k$ be the event: "the $k$ throw is Pile" and $F_k$ be "the $k$ throw is face"
>   I would like to prove that there **exist a unique** probability on $\bigl(\Omega,\mathcal{P}(\Omega)\bigr)$ such that :
>
> 1. for all $k$ the probability of $P_k$ is equal to $p$ and $F_k$ is $1-p$ with $p\in [0,1].$
> 2. The result of different throws are independent

Progress and where I am stuck :

Let $\Pi(\omega):=\{i\in [[0,1]]: w_i=P\}$, clearly we have $$\Bbb{P}(\{\omega\})=\prod_{i\in \Pi(\omega)}\Bbb{P}(P_i)\times\prod_{i\in \Pi(\omega)^c}\Bbb{P}(F_i).$$ Now the first hypothesis implies that:
$$
\Bbb{P}(\{\omega\})=p^{\vert\Pi(\omega) \vert}(1-p)^{n-\vert\Pi(\omega) \vert}.
$$
 This proves the unicity because $\Omega$ is countable.

To continue, I need to prove that if $\Bbb{P}$ defined by my second equation, then it's a probability, which means here $\displaystyle\sum_{\omega\in \Omega}\Bbb{P}(\{\omega\})=1.$

*And I am stuck here, I am not sure how can I express the sum.* Pretty sure it's about to write down a double sums, I never understood the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\binom{n}{k}$ many $\omega$ that all have probability $p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$. And this holds for each $k$. So you have to sum $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}$ which by Newton's binomial formula equals $(p + (1-p))^n = 1$.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is more about expressing the sum, I can see the argument but I would like to understand the process, as : $\sum_{\omega\in \Omega}\Bbb{P}(\{\omega\})=\cdots=1$

Comment: $ = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\omega \in \Omega, k \textrm{ piles dans } \omega} \mathbb{P}(\{\omega\}) = \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\omega \in \Omega, k \textrm{ piles dans } \omega} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} $